# Как установить onClickListner в RecyclerView в Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, recyclerview.adapter, onclicklistener

```
class Adapter(val itemsList: ArrayList<Template>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>()  {
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
      val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
      val h : ViewHolder = ViewHolder(v)
      h.itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { })
      return ViewHolder(v)
  }

  override fun getItemCount(): Int {
      return itemsList.size
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
      val tamplates: Template = itemsList[position]
      holder?.title1?.text = tamplates.getTitle()
      holder?.content1?.text = tamplates.getBody()
      holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
          Log.d("CLIIICK " ,  tamplates.getId().toString())
      })

  }

  class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
      val title1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title) as TextView
      val content1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.content) as TextView

  }

}
```

Мне нужно при нажатии на элемент ресайклер вью получать его данные

Answer (score 1):

Можно при создание холдера устанавливать слушателя на вью (тогда класс холдера должен быть inner классом чтоб мы могли поучить доступ к itemsList).

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
  val title1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title) as TextView
  val content1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.content) as TextView
    init {
         itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (adapterPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
           val template = itemsList[adapterPosition]
        }
}
```

Вариант с установкой слушателя в onBindViewHolder() тоже приемлемый, только в этом случае слушатель будет каждый раз при bindе заново устанавливаться.